# PDO fetchall query, show multiple results but only 1 per ID

Tags: php, pdo

My question wasn't clear so I'm editing a bit.

I have a website where people can bid on stuff and on their account page they can track there bids. But if one person bids twice on a product they see that product twice. So I only want to show there highest bid per product.

This is my query:

```
$objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = :ownerid ORDER BY prijs DESC');
```

Greetings,

Bram

EDIT

```
$objGetHighest = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = :ownerid GROUP BY adid');
$objGetHighest->bindParam('ownerid', $member_id);
$objGetHighest->execute();
$objGetHighestFetch = $objGetHighest->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($objGetHighestFetch as $key) {
  $adID = $key['adid'];
  //This echoes 3 values which is good!!

  $objGetBid = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE adid = :adid');
  $objGetBid->bindParam('adid', $adID);
  $objGetBid->execute();
  $objGetBidFetch = $objGetBid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

So this is what I got right now. The $adID echoes 3 values out of the 4 ads where 2 of them have the same ID so this is good. But then I do another query and then I get then I see the bids of the ID which he shows once.

[image: Table]

Comment: use GROUP BY product_ID

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I use this in my query I get 2 result instead of 3 is this the right syntax? `SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = :ownerid GROUP BY adid = :adid ORDER BY prijs DESC`

Comment: do you want to select all of ownerid with specific value?

Comment: Yes because this is on the account page so the owner only gets to see his own bids. And then I want to show the owner highest bids.

Comment: if you want to show all the bids for one(1) owner who had login to your app, just remove the GROUP BY. use SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = 'ownerid value' ORDER BY prijs DESC. Thats all, it will give you all bids in a high sort

Comment: If I do that and the owner had bid twice on the same item he will see the item twice instead of just his highest bid.

Comment: please edit your question, show your example table data and show what your expect for the result is. It will make me easy to solve it

Comment: @angvee And added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. just add GROUP BY adid, it works like you want. Cheers! hope helpfully.

```
$objGetHighest = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE ownerid = :ownerid GROUP BY adid");
$objGetHighest->bindParam('ownerid', $member_id);
$objGetHighest->execute();
$objGetHighestFetch = $objGetHighest->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($objGetHighestFetch as $key) {
  $adID = $key['adid'];
  //This echoes 3 values which is good!!
  //echo $adID."<br />";

  $objGetBid = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabs WHERE adid = '$adID' GROUP BY adid ");
  $objGetBid->execute();
  $objGetBidFetch = $objGetBid->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  print_r($objGetBidFetch);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if want to get one higher rows, you can try this, hope will help you. Cheers!

```
$query = $objDatabaseAds->prepare('SELECT * FROM bieden WHERE ownerid = :ownerid ORDER BY prijs DESC LIMIT 1');

$query->execute();

while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     echo $data['column_name'];
     echo $data['ownerid'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry my answer for your previous question. so, what do you want is just get one higher rows from your table? if that correct, just add your query LIMIT 1.